# C# Application Threading

Tags: c#, winforms

So I am creating an application that will have a splash screen that loads resources, and when complete will load the Main form of the application. In times past I've just let the splash screen own the thread and stay hidden, but I'm toying with the idea of actually letting my Main form be the thread owner, but I'm having trouble transitioning between forms. My current approach is

```
void main(String[] args)
{
   ApplicationContext appContext = new ApplicationContext(new SplashScreen());
   appContext.ThreadExit += appContext_ThreadExit;
   Application.Run(appContext);
}
place
private void appContext_ThreadExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Application.Run(new MainForm());
}
```

This give me the error that you can't start a new message loop on the thread. So how do I go about properly executing this transition? Or am I already using the best method by allowing the SplashScreen to own the thread?

Comment: why don't you use async? let the splash screen load the resurces using async/await

Comment: wouldn't more code be helpful? you are just show limited code set

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with, but if anyone has a more elegant or proper way to do it feel free to let me know.

```
bool isLoading = true;

MainForm.OnLoad()
   -> creates and runs SplashScreen

MainForm.OnShow()
   -> if isLoading is true, re-hide

SplashScreen.LoadingComplete
   -> event to signal completion of loading events

MainForm.SplashScreenLoadingComplete
   -> handler sets isLoading to false
   -> calls Show() this time form will show
```

I handle the loading in the SplashScreen with a background worker